# ATMega328P chip on breadboard does not work properly

Tags: arduino-uno, breadboard

I wanted to get some help about my ATMega328P on my breadboard. I programmed a simple clock like this -

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht.h>
#include <DS3231.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); 
dht DHT;
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

void setup() {
  rtc.begin();
  lcd.begin(16,2);

}

void loop() {

  int chk = DHT.read11(9);
  delay(1000);
  lcd.print("Temp: ");
  lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print((char)223);
  lcd.print("C");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humi: ");
  lcd.print(DHT.humidity);
  lcd.print(" %");
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);

  delay(5000);

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Time:  ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Date: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  delay(5000); 

  lcd.clear();
 }
```

The code works when ATMega328P is connected on the Arduino Board itself, everything is showing correctly. But when I remove the chip (when it's already programmed) and place it on the breadboard, do all the necessary wirings, it only outputs me the words Humi and Temp without even showing the proper values (-999.0 degrees it shows me). I triple-checked my connections and found nothing. And after those 5 seconds of waiting, I finally got Time, and nothing is there, only the text, not even those weird numbers. And it doesn't even reload back to Temp and Humi, it just stays on Time word forever.

I have feeling that loop doesn't work properly somehow.

EDIT: I found out what was the problem about reseting, BUT STILL the proper values doesn't show up

Can you help me out, please?

Comment: Why do you suspect the loop() function, when you've already seen it work correctly? You've supplied the code but you already know that works. We need to see the breadboard wiring that you said is failing, since that is the difference between working and non-working systems. Despite triple-checking your wiring, you've apparently found a problem with reset. What was the problem and what was the solution? Could that guide you to other wiring problems? Please post a schematic, or at least a clear and accurate wiring diagram of your breadboard. Without that, we can only guess.

Comment: Did you add some (bypass) capacitors on the breadboard, between VCC and GND? Place them as near to the chip as possible. Secondly, try wiggling all the wires in the breadboard. Sometimes their don't make proper connection.

Comment: Pretty sure a hardware issue related to the breadboard environment...

Comment: Alright, I figured it out myself, thanks. Yeah, there was a hardware problem. A5 pin somehow didn't work properly.. Now it does.